# How to cancel an upstream CSS declaration?

Tags: css

The following declarations block at the top of my CSS file:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

...is *almost* what I want, but not quite.  Closer to the mark would be the following "fantasy CSS":

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

(?!button) * {   /* i.e. "everything except button" */
  border: 0;
}
```

I've tried to simulate this fantasy with

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

button {
  border: initial;
}
```

...to no avail.  (I gather that, for `button` at least, the `initial` value for the `border` property is in fact `0`, or something effectively equivalent.)

Of course, I could find out the value that `border` has for `button` in the absence of the `border: 0;` declaration, and then *explicitly* reset this value; e.g.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

button {
  border: 2px outset rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

...but this is certainly *not the same thing* as *cancelling* the earlier `border: 0;` declaration.  For one thing, the actual values for the `button { border: ...; }` declaration are bound to vary with the browser, the OS, etc.

Is there any way to really *cancel* an earlier CSS declaration?  IOW, is there any way to express in CSS (or otherwise implement) something that is *semantically equivalent* to the "fantasy CSS" I showed above?

---

(Of course, I realize that I can always forgo the `*` as the selector for the `border: 0;` declaration and simply use a selector that includes every html5 tag other than `button`, but this does not answer my question, it only circumvents it.  Therefore, strictly speaking, this workaround is besides the point as far as this post is concerned.  Equally besides the point would be some quibbles I have about it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `:not()` selector (the `*` is implied):

```
:not(button) {
    margin: 0; /* applied to all elements except <button> */
}
```

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0):

just be redundant.
instead of *, use:

```
    html, body, body div, span, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
     abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
     small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 0;
                 border: 0;
                  font-size: 100%;
          vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

you can add or remove other tags.

For more complex inicialitazions, I recommend you to use the  html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet , that you can find here  [html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)

Comment: Even better than resetting: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ (preserves defaults but removes differences between user agents)